# How to get NSAlert sheet to return focus to calling window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an OS X prefpane that calls a NSAlert sheet with:

```
 [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[[self mainView] window] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(unsavedChangesAlertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

Which shows the alert sheet attached to the System Preferences application fine, but when I click the sheet's OK button, it closes and doesn't return focus to System Preferences. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending that window a `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` message at the end of your `-unsavedChangesAlertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:` method.

Comment: For some reason, my window doesn't have that selector. I'm calling the window from my prefpane like:

    [[self mainView] window]

Comment: timmerk: All windows (i.e., all instances of NSWindow or any subclass thereof) respond to that selector. It would help if you posted the actual exception message.

Comment: Peter: that's what I thought, but Xcode keeps saying window might not respond to it. There was no exception, but I figured out the problem - inside my unsavedChangesAlertDidEnd method, I launch a background app using NSWorkspace which caused the loss of focus. Thanks all!

Comment: @K_T You should post your answer as the answer to this question and accept it. That is perfectly acceptable behavior on stackoverflow!